# Why is it taking so long to GC System.Threading.OverlappedData?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, asyncsocket

I'm running my application through a memory profiler to check for leaks. Things seem to be sort of OK, but I'm getting a lot of these OverlappedData that seems to be hanging around in the finalizer queue doing next to nothing. They are the result of overlapped IO that has been cancelled by shutting down the underlying `NetworkStream` on either end of the connection.

The network stream itself is disposed. There are no live instances of `NetworkStream` anywhere.

Typically they're rooted in something that is called an `OverlappedDataCacheLine`.I'm calling `EndRead` in a callback the first thing I do, so no call to `BeginRead` should be without it's corresponding `EndRead`.

This is a pretty typical look of who's keeping it from the tool

[image: OverlappedData is being help up]

In the end it *does* get GC'd but it takes forever - in the order of half an hour to kill everything when I've started about a thousand streams, put them in a async call to `BeginRead` and shutting them down after about a minute.

This program reproduces the problem somewhat against a webserver on port 80. Any webserver will do really.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var clients = new List<TcpClient>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
            var client = new TcpClient();
            clients.Add(client);

            client.BeginConnect("localhost", 80, connectResult =>
                {
                    client.EndConnect(connectResult);

                    var stream = client.GetStream();
                    stream.BeginRead(new byte[1000], 0, 1000, result =>
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                stream.EndRead(result);
                                Console.WriteLine("Finished (should not happen)");
                            }
                            catch
                            {
                                // Expect to find an IO exception here
                                Console.WriteLine("Faulted");                               
                            }
                        }, stream);     
                }, client);             
        }

        Thread.Sleep(10000); // Make sure everything has time to connect

        foreach (var tcpClient in clients)
        {
            tcpClient.GetStream().Close();
            tcpClient.Close();
        }
        clients.Clear(); // Make sure the entire list can be GC'd

        Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite); // Wait forever. See in profiler to see the overlapped IO take forever to go away
    }
}
```

Granted, this program doesn't take forever to clear up the thousand `OverlappedData` since it's way smaller than the real application but it does take a while to do its thing. I get warnings for a stuck finalizer when running my real stuff instead of this testing application. It doesn't do much in my application, just tries to close down everything that might not have been closed and makes sure that there's no references being kept to anything anywhere.

It doesn't seem to matter at all if I call `Dispose()` or `Close()` on the client and it's stream. The result is the same.

Any clue as to why this happens and how to avoid this? It the CLR being smart on me and keeping these pinned blocks of memory intact in preparation for new calls perhaps? And why is the finalizer being so incredibly slow to complete?

**Update** After doing some incredibly stupid load tests by putting a glass of water on the F5 key and getting some coffee it seems that something triggers a more complete GC under stress that collects these things. So there doesn't actually *seem* to be a real issue but still it would be nice to know what actually goes on here and why collecting this object is magnitudes slower than other objects and if this could potentially be an issue at a later stage with fragmented memory and such.

Comment: Failing to call EndXxxx results in resources getting leaked for 10 minutes.

Comment: So, if the underlying stream is closed on you while you're waiting for the callback to be called, can you in any way use the `EndXxx`, considering that there's nothing waiting except the callback? I mean, if things fault the callback would still be called, no?

Comment: Closing the socket will complete the operation.  EndRead will clean up those resources and generate an ObjectDisposed exception.  Just make sure that you still call EndRead in your real code.

Comment: @HansPassant That's pretty much what I do. I mean, it gets cleaned up properly *eventually*, it just takes a very long time to do so. It's not insane amounts of memory but it's a couple of thousand of these objects floating around if you put a lot of load on the server. The GC seems to pick a few off every now and again, and from what I can see they're only around ~120 bytes in size. There's no 10 minute delay from when I stop the load until it starts to dispose of these objects. The disposing starts as soon as it can but takes a long time to complete. Other objects are disposed a lot quicker.

Comment: Well, how often does the GC actually run after the abort?  Usually a program stops allocating memory when you stop doing stuff.  Like when you have no live connections anymore.  Which also stops collections.

Comment: @HansPassant Oh, you mean that the GC isn't running as much when I'm just idling around waiting for connections? That's news to me - and it would also explain why I'm not seeing these things explode in size during load and why the collection seems to happen a lot more efficiently when the service is actually doing things. I'm never calling the GC to collect explicitly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, it seems clear now what's going on.  Garbage collections only ever happen when you allocate memory.  It requires at least 2 megabytes of allocations, the typical initial size of the generation 0 GC heap to trigger a GC.  In other words, a program that does nothing will never run a GC and you'll see any objects that haven't been collected yet in the heap with a memory profiler for a long time.

Which is a good explanation of what you describe.  After you terminate all connections, your program doesn't have to do anything anymore.  So won't allocate much if any memory so won't trigger a collection.  If your profiler doesn't show collections then you can see them with Perfmon.exe.  This is otherwise not a problem at all, just a side effect of how a garbage collector works.

Only ever worry about leaks when you have clear evidence that a program has a run-away resource consumption problem.

Comment: Thanks! I tested this out and it checks out. I didn't know about this behaviour. I had a memory leak unrelated to this, and while profiling the application to find it this popped up and I wondered if this was the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Try obtaining client from `AsyncResult` to rule out any lambda closure issues.

`TcpClient t = (TcpClient)connectResult.AsyncState;`

Also, shouldn't you call `EndConnect` *after* to finished your processing?

Comment: None of the instances are rooted in a `Closure`, changing it to use the `AsyncState` doesn't change anything. They're floating around properly in the finalization queue. `EndConnect` should be called there, or the async operation won't finish. Changing it doesn't make a difference.